# Scanner and ArrayList Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to accept user input into this `ArrayList` with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers, press 0 to exit");
        i = sc.nextInt();
        if (i == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is just `[]`.

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `i < list.size()` what is the size of the list at first iteration of loop?

Comment: Also, even if the loop gets executed, you are modifying `int i` inside the loop, which is a big issue as well

Comment: Can I not have the loop expand as i'm iterating though.

Comment: You can have the loop expand, but 1) it is unnecessary and a while loop is a much better option 2) you should not modify the value of i inside your for loop if you want to keep i as the counter through the loop. You should create a separate int, and scan the number into that int

Comment: Also, the use of i = sc.nextInt() isn't a good idea when you're using i as the loop variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list.size()` is 0 at the start, so you won't go into your for-loop.
You can do something like

```
int i = 0;
do {
      System.out.println("Enter numbers, press 0 to exit");
      i = sc.nextInt();
      if(i != 0) {
           list.add(i);
      }
} while(i != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo:

```
    ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList <Integer> ();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
```

Since list is empty at the beginning, `list.size()` is 0 and i is always smaller than `list.size()`.